# Azure Storage Account Firewall Permissions for Vulnerability Assessment

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have created a storage account for use in storing the results of an Azure Vulnerability Assessment on an Azure SQL Database.

If the firewall on the storage account is disabled, allowing access from all networks, Azure Vulnerability Scans work as expected.

If the firewall is enabled, the Azure Vulnerability Scan on the SQL Database reports an error, saying the storage account is not valid or does not exist.

Checking the box for "Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account." in Networking properties for the storage account does not work to resolve this issue, though it is the recommended step in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-vulnerability-assessment-storage

[Allow Azure Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvVTm.png)

What other steps could resolve this issue, rather than just disabling the firewall?

Comment: Hello @.JeffStoker , May i know if you have followed the step 4 of the document provided by you i.e. adding the subnet used by the sql managed instance in the firewall to allow the connection ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-vulnerability-assessment-storage#store-va-scan-results-for-azure-sql-managed-instance-in-a-storage-account-that-can-be-accessed-behind-a-firewall-or-vnet

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the subnet and vnet that is being used by the SQL Managed Instance as mentioned in the document you are following . You can refer the below screenshot:

[image]

After enabling the service endpoint status as shown in the above image , Click Add . After adding the vnet it should look like below:

[image]

After this is done , Click on save and you should be able to resolve the issue.

**Reference:**

[Store Vulnerability Assessment scan results in a storage account accessible behind firewalls and VNets - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-vulnerability-assessment-storage#store-va-scan-results-for-azure-sql-managed-instance-in-a-storage-account-that-can-be-accessed-behind-a-firewall-or-vnet)

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I have made some progress, not with this exact solution, but with something similar. I also needed to add an existing virtual network on the SQL Server networking side as the service endpoint had already been enabled on the storage account side. This has at least allowed me to move to the point where RBAC permissions need to be granted.

Thanks for the push in the right direction.